# Draft JS editor does not update it's content when its value changed by parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, draftjs

I've a simple use case: There's a DraftEditor component which takes `value` as its prop and create a editor state based on `value` (empty or with content). It possible that the `value` gets changed by the parent and when it does, I expect the Draft Editor to update it's content as well.  Here's my `DraftEditor` component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

export default ({ value }) => {
  const initialState = value
    ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value)))
    : EditorState.createEmpty();
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(initialState);

  return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />;
};
```

The problem: When `value` is updated by the parent component, the contents of `Editor` is not getting updated. Instead, it just shows the content it was initialized with.  The workaround I found is to manually call `setEditorState` when the `value` changes, but I feel this step is unnecessary as when the component re-renders I expect the editor to recalculate it's internal state as well? May be I am missing something here?

Any idea why the `Editor` is not updating it's internal state?

Here's a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-sanderson-i95vd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic problem is

```js
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(initialState);
```

uses it's parameter `initialState` only once (on initial run-through), no matter how many times `initialState` changes.

When using `useState()` and there is a prop (or other) dependency, pair it with a `useEffect()` to make things reactive.

This may seem a bit backwards, but a lot of (most of) the hooks are about keeping things the same when the Function component is re-run. So `useState()` only updates `editorState` via `setEditorState`, after the initial call.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

export default ({ value }) => {

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const state = value
      ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value)))
      : EditorState.createEmpty();
    setEditorState(state);
  }, [value]); // add 'value' to the dependency list to recalculate state when value changes.

  return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />;
};
```

---

In the code above, editorState will be null on initial component call. If this is a problem for the `Editor` component, you can externalize the state calculation in a function and call it for `useState()` and within `useEffect()`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor, EditorState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

export default ({ value }) => {

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(calcState(value));

  useEffect(() => {
    setEditorState(calcState(value));
  }, [value]); // add 'value' to the dependency list to recalculate state when value changes.

  return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />;
};

const calcState = (value) => {
  return value
    ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value)))
    : EditorState.createEmpty();
}
```

---

Since those two hooks are used together a lot, I tend to pair them in a custom hook to encapsulate the detail.

The difference is that the custom hook runs every time the Component runs, but `editorState` still only updates when value changes.

**Custom hook**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { EditorState, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

export const useConvertEditorState = (value) => {

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(calcState(value));

  useEffect(() => {
    setEditorState(calcState(value));
  }, [value]); 

  return [editorState, setEditorState];
}

const calcState = (value) => {
  return value
    ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value)))
    : EditorState.createEmpty();
}
```

**Component**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Editor } from "draft-js";
import { useConvertEditorState } from './useConvertEditorState'

export default ({ value }) => {

  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useConvertEditorState(value);

  return <Editor editorState={editorState} onChange={setEditorState} />;
};
```

Comment: That makes sense.. I did have this implemented before, but wanted to know the reasoning behind 'useEffect` fix.